# Changing the cmake CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS depending on the directory in which the source files are located

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a cmake project, which compiles and links various libraries to my code it. My problem is that the CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS variable contains a macro definition which when used to compile the sources in one of the project's directories generates a conflict. Is it possible to define CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS directory depended i.e. (in pseudo code).

```
if [ dir1 ] then 
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "-DMPICH_IGNORE_CXX_SEEK ${LIB1} ${LIB2} -Wno-sign-compare -O3 -DVARSUB=double ")
if [ dir2 ] then
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "-DMPICH_IGNORE_CXX_SEEK ${LIB1} ${LIB2} -Wno-sign-compare -O3 ")
fi
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Use `COMPILE_DEFINITIONS` inside your sub-directory and add `-DVARSUB=double` to it.

Comment: First of all I would like to thank you for your reply. Could you give me a practical example how to include the COMPILE_DEFINITIONS. I have one single CMakeLists.txt file, should I somehow add additional CMakeLists.txt files to my sub directories?

Comment: Yes, I would have a CMakeLists.txt for the sub-directory.